# How do I export a DataTable to new DBF file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dbf

I have a DataTable that I've populated with a variety of data from other datatables, and the field names change often. My question is how would I export this DataTable to a DBF file?

Here is what I've come up with but it simply doesn't know how to extract the data from the DataTable...

```
Dim dBaseConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(“Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;” & “Data Source=” & path & “;” & “Extended Properties=dBase IV”)

        dBaseConnection.Open()

        Dim SQLCreateCommand As String
        SQLCreateCommand = "SELECT * INTO NewTable From " & DataTable
        Dim dBaseCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLCreateCommand, dBaseConnection)

        dBaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dBaseConnection.Close()
```

Comment: A Google search turned this up: [https://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.DataExport/Program-Guide/How-to-Export-Datatable-to-DBF.html](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.DataExport/Program-Guide/How-to-Export-Datatable-to-DBF.html)

Comment: Not a vb.net solution... but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the FASTDBF lib referece downloaded from here: https://github.com/SocialExplorer/FastDBF

```
 Private Sub ExportListButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportListButton.Click

    Dim ExportedDbf = New DbfFile(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
    ExportedDbf.Open(Path.Combine("C:\WORK\A_TEST", "Combined.dbf"), FileMode.Create)

    For Each col In CombinedDataTable.Columns
        ExportedDbf.Header.AddColumn(New DbfColumn(col.ToString, DbfColumn.DbfColumnType.Character, 50, 0))
    Next

    Dim Counter As Integer = 0

    For Each row In CombinedDataTable.Rows

        Dim ColumnCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim NewRec = New DbfRecord(ExportedDbf.Header)

        For Each col In CombinedDataTable.Columns

            NewRec(ColumnCounter) = CombinedDataTable.Rows(Counter)(col).ToString
            ColumnCounter = ColumnCounter + 1
        Next

        ExportedDbf.Write(NewRec, True)
        Counter = Counter + 1

    Next

    ExportedDbf.Close()

End Sub
```